# data binding two different objects with same user control wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have two objects with different properties,

eg

```
class foo
{
     int age;
     string name;
}

class bar
{
     string kind;
     int length;
}
```

I have a gridview usercontrol that can easily bind one class to its rows and columns but I don't want to make another usercontrol just for the second class, id rather reuse the same control for displaying the data, how can I do this in WPF databinding?

Id rather you didn't post code examples, just point me in the direction, I have looked at data templates but they seem to want the property to bind to, in this case I have two different objects.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the `UserControl`, nor the `GridView` where you define what your data items will look like, so you can easily display items from different classes in one `UserControl`. Instead, you define how each class should be rendered by declaring `DataTemplate`s:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:foo}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding age}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:bar}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding kind}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding length}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Of course, you'd need to use a collection of type `object` if you want to be able to put different types of objects in it:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; set; }
```

...

```
Items = GetFoos();
// Or Items = GetBars();
```

...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

Reading the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN should help you understand this all better. However, I wouldn't recommend this approach as you'd continually have to cast objects back to their proper types. You're much better off declaring different `UserControl`s for each data type being displayed or edited.